# Only intercept double taps

Tags: android, android-webview, android-2.3-gingerbread, gesturedetector

I currently have a GestureDetector on a webView that I want to respond to double taps.  However, the webView then ignores all single taps - presumably I have overridden this behaviour too.

I am looking for:

- Double taps to be detected by my code and dealt with by my activity
- Regular taps to be dealt with as normal by the WebView

Here's what I have so far:

```
final WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebViewClient webrules = new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView web,String url){
            return false;
        }
    };
    web.setWebViewClient(webrules);
    WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("**APP**", "Double Tap event");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    gestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);

    web.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

    });
```

How can I leave the normal single taps to the webView to deal with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try returning false in your `onDown` method. Returning true "means" that the event has been consumed, and is therefore not passed on.

Comment: Triggers some errors and warnings but works fine, thanks XD *waits 6 minutes*